# Cannot understand LIBSVM's svmpredict output

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am trying to predict the probability values of my testing data using the following command:

```
[predict_label,accuracy,prob_values]=svmpredict(yte,xte,model,'-b 1');
```

The output (prob_values) is:

```
# Created by Octave 4.0.0, Tue Aug 16 20:01:59 2016 IST   <prashant@prashant-Lenovo-Z50-70>
# name: prob_values
# type: matrix
# rows: 342
# columns: 3
 0.9784796387902676 0.01578942726269292 0.005730933947039552
 0.7423959342205719 0.2518766107216108 0.005727455057817437
 0.3024602585760641 0.686248271105996 0.01129147031793989
 0.3502290809371524 0.6386005690732945 0.01117034998955301
 0.3600810697654571 0.629618027125051 0.01030090310949171
```

and so on....

It cannot understand why is it outputting three probability values corresponding to each row? Am I missing something?

Comment: Never used this lib directly (only wrappers), but: the output make me believe, you got three classes and the output is the probability-vector (each row sums up to one). Sample 0 is probably of class 0 (~98%), sample 2 is probably of class 1 (~69%). (Keep in mind, that probability-.output of SVMs are just crude approximations; it's not natural in the SVM-theory).

Comment: But I've got only two classes. Actually, I am working on breast cancer diagnosis using the UCI ML dataset. The tumor can be either malignant or benign. And if not use the library directly, can you suggest me some other way to rest the accuracy of the classifier? I want to improve the accuracy by looking at the "confidence" with which the classifier predicts a class.

Comment: Well the output looks like 3 classes. Maybe you did something wrong with your data-setup. Look at the unique-values in your targets. Things might be more complex if these are some raw values of some multiclass-approach like OneVsRest or OneVsAll. There are special accuracy metrics (which you should use). scikit-learn makes a lot of this stuff muich easier to tackle (and wraps libsvm).

Comment: Oh man. A simple zero at the end of the file in the first column was the cause for the extra class (besides 1 and -1). Thanks for the help.